# openldap user can't login when using tcsh

Tags: bash, ldap, nfs, centos7, pam

I would appreciate any help in the following problem:

I have an openladp (2.3.39) server (Fedora 8) which authenticates users from other ldap clients (various versions of Fedora). On my attempt to upgrade the whole infrastructure, ldap users with tcsh (as their default shell) cannot login in a new client running CentOS 7. On the contrary, ldap users with bash as well as local users (no matter their default shell) login without a problem.

Ldap tcsh users can't login neither from console nor from ssh. While from console, the message I receive is:

```
pam_unix(login:auth) authentication failure
pam_unix(login:session) session opened for user
```

and from ssh (without a failure part):

```
pam_unix(sshd:session) session opened for user
```

However, the user never gets a shell prompt, indicating that the login hangs. I have no idea whether the problem is pam related, but find below my /etc/pam.d/system-auth-ac as it was created automatically by system-authconfig:

```
#%PAM-1.0
# This file is auto-generated.
# User changes will be destroyed the next time authconfig is run.
auth        required      pam_env.so
auth        sufficient    pam_unix.so nullok try_first_pass
auth        requisite     pam_succeed_if.so uid >= 1000 quiet_success
auth        sufficient    pam_ldap.so use_first_pass
auth        required      pam_deny.so

account     required      pam_access.so
account     required      pam_unix.so broken_shadow
account     sufficient    pam_localuser.so
account     sufficient    pam_succeed_if.so uid < 1000 quiet
account     [default=bad success=ok user_unknown=ignore] pam_ldap.so
account     required      pam_permit.so

password    requisite     pam_pwquality.so try_first_pass local_users_only retry=3 authtok_type=
password    sufficient    pam_unix.so sha512 shadow nullok try_first_pass use_authtok
password    sufficient    pam_ldap.so use_authtok
password    required      pam_deny.so

session     optional      pam_keyinit.so revoke
session     required      pam_limits.so
-session     optional      pam_systemd.so
session     [success=1 default=ignore] pam_succeed_if.so service in crond quiet use_uid
session     required      pam_unix.so
session     optional      pam_ldap.so
```

Thanks in advance.

**Update:** The problem seems to be related with the nfs exported home directories. If I unmount the shared partition from the client, the user is `Logging in with home = "/"`, though.

Comment: a) is `tcsh` actually installed b) is `tcsh`  defined in `/etc/shells` as a valid login shell?

Comment: @HBruijn yes. That's why local tcsh users have no problem to login.

Comment: Is the path for the shell in the LDAP entry for the user valid? Eg. if it points to `/bin/tcsh`, is there a valid shell there?

Comment: @Sven Yes, /bin/tcsh is there.

Comment: And does `loginShell` in the LDAP directory for `tcsh` users point to `/bin/tcsh`? Also, what happens if you just  do `su <username>` as root for the affected users?

Comment: @Sven Yes it does. In fact, the users can login normally in the other (older) clients. `su` hangs in the same way.

Comment: http://www.perl.com/doc/FMTEYEWTK/versus/csh.whynot - maybe you should help people figure out that csh is past its prime

Answer (score 1):

Finally it turned out that nfs was responsible. Client was v.4, while server v.3 and therefore, mount option `sec=sys` was necessary at the client part.

Thanks to all who bothered.